# Is there a way to overload/intercept function calls on overloaded objects in Perl?

Tags: perl, function, overloading

In a manner similar to what is possible with overloaded operators, is there a way to apply some sort of magic to a variable so that the following:

```
my $magic_var = ...;

some_function($magic_var);
```

will result in something like this:

```
call_function(\&some_function, $magic_var)
```

If `some_function` was not defined, I could just use an `AUTOLOAD` sub to catch the call, but when it is defined, I am not aware of a way to intercept the call (without something crazy like injecting wrappers around all of the caller's subs, or temporarily undefining all the subs).

Another way to put it is I would like to write `use overload sin => \&my_sin;` but have `sin` be any function, and have it call a `nomethod` like sub whenever the overloaded object is used in a function call.

EDIT:

By popular request, the reason that I was looking into this was because I am working on a Perl5 version of the Perl6 whatever star.  However, after looking into the Perl6 implementation more, it seems that it also does not deal with functions being called on `Whatever`, so it seems like I won't have to try and deal with function calls (just operators and method calls).

If anyone is interested, the module is up on CPAN: [Whatever](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Whatever).

Feedback / Comments are welcome.

Comment: mmmm, source filters? :) More seriously, is there some reason you can’t just find the operator that they will eventually use on the $magic_var` done in the function and overload *that*?

Comment: @tchrist => I've gone down the source filter road before, its not pretty.  Right now, that is how my objects are behaving (they will be passed into a sub and then bind to the first operator that is used on them).  But I was hoping to be able to catch the call earlier, both to increase the laziness of the operation, and to deal with edge cases like if the sub tees the value and then sends it down multiple operator paths.

Comment: Also, if there was some way to catch the application of builtin functions, it would be ideal (the current way of catching the typecast (`"" +0 bool` and the like) ends up loosing the overloading after the function call).

Comment: Context please! Why do you want to do this? What's your ultimate intent?

Comment: The answer to the question you asked would be a straight No. However, if you'd step back a little and explain what you're actually trying to achieve, it's quite possible you'd get a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the [tie](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) mechanism?